# How to make Youtube video responsive for mobile but NOT fullscreen on desktop

Tags: responsive-design, youtube

Apologies if this has been asked before, I found similar but not exactly what I'm looking for.

I've found various online tools to embed a responsive Youtube video, however in doing so, it makes them huge on desktop (as it's set to 100% I think and taking up the whole screen).

I found a piece of code that apparently fixes this problem here https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/help-resizing-embed-youtube-video-with-css/210568 but am unsure where that code fits into what I have so far (i'm a complete novice with code).

Would someone be able to help and provide me with the full piece of code I will need (I only have access to the HTML), so that I can just slot in the youtube link?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Abby, welcome, but sorry. You need to show us a minimal reproducible example for us to be able to help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You can make a YouTube Embed responsive with `min` and `max` width and height mentioned in the CSS. You can edit the code as per your needs and **I do not know why Stack Overflow is not running the code, you can save it and run it manually.**
As:

```html
<iframe class="yt" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/668nUCeBHyY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<style>
    .yt{
    width: 100%;
    min-width:200;
    max-width:800;
    height: auto;
    min-height:400;
    }
</style>
```